# How can i link mutiple files correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, undefined-reference

im new to programing. i am having problems with linking all my files together. Does anyone know how to fix this error. Thank you very much!
Here is the program that i compile:

add.h:

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

add.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile this program there is an error: `undefined reference to` add(int, int)'`. I tried to firgue out how to link these files by changing task.json:

```
    {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                ${file},
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                ""
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

i changed "${file}" in args to "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp" but there is an error like this:

```
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Hocbai/**.cpp: Invalid argument
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?
Thank you very much for reading!!!

I hope to see my program can link together

Comment: Your bug is `${file},` the official VSCode documentation tells you about this and how use more than 1 file here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: VSCode is a very advanced, complex development tool that's designed for highly skilled, experienced developers who have a wide range of domain knowledge, like the JSON configuration syntax, and familiarity with obscure compiler flags and options. It is not meant to be used for people who are just starting out learning C++ and who do not have established development experience, those people will find other development environments, like VS community edition (Windows) or emacs+make (Linux, MacOS), easier to use.

Comment: `C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Hocbai/**.cpp` Are you sure you added `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",` and not `"${workspaceFolder}/**.cpp",`

Comment: The msvc documentation is the same as MinGW for this: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_modifying-tasksjson)